# Remove DataBinder.Eval field if it is null or blank

Tags: c#, gridview, eval, databinder

Actually I am binding some data on tooltip of a Image control in gridview.

all is working fine. see my code below

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/images.jpg" ToolTip='<%# (Eval("Comments").ToString().Length == 0? "": "Late Reason - " + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comments")) + (Eval("Out_Comments").ToString().Length == 0? "" :"| Out Reason - "+ DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Out_Comments")) %>' />
```

my requirement is that when  Comments field is null or blank in database then this extra text "Late Reason - " should remove from the tool tip and if the Comments field is not blank or null then this extra text should be there in tooltip. And it also does same for the Out_Comments field which is having extra text "Out Reason - ".

how can I do this?

[image]

Comment: One solution would be just dont show the tooltip if field is blank or null.

Comment: there are two fields Comments and Out_Comments. I can hide tooltip if both are blank or null. What if there is blank but another is not?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/images.jpg"
            ToolTip='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Comments") as string)
        ? !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Out_Comments") as string)
          ? "Late Reason - " + Eval("Comments") + " | Out Reason - " + Eval("Out_Comments")
          : "Late Reason - " + Eval("Comments")
        : "Out Reason - " + Eval("Out_Comments")%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Edit: changed the null checking to `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Comments") as string)` to check for empty/blank strings.

Comment: not working. by the why where is image and it's tool tip property?

Comment: now see I have attached an image. Your solution is not working.according to Your solution if Comments is null or blank although it is showing "Late Reason - " but my requirement is that it shouln't show this extra text.

Answer (score 0):

You should be handling this logic in the GridView RowDataBound Event.

```
Image img = e.Row.FindControl("Image1");

if( img != null ) {

    //Apply Logic Here

    img.ToolTip = //End result of logic
}
```